# PHP Retrieve all keys of associate array based on search

Tags: php, arrays

I have example array below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'item-1'
            [type] => typeA
            [ids] => Array(123, 456, 999)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'item-2'
            [type] => typeA
            [ids] => Array(555, 4444, 666)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'item-3'
            [type] => typeB
            [ids] => null
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'item-4'
            [type] => typeB
            [ids] => Array(555)
        )
 )
```

As an example, I want to search the array for all entries where type is typeA or id = 555.  I just need to retrieve the name fields (or at least the keys and from there the names).  In the hypothetical example, the search would result in item-1, item-2 and item-4

I tried a few different PHP functions. For example

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($parent_array, 'type'), 'typeA');
```

The above works for retrieving keys when search is based on the [type] field.  But doesn't work for [ids].

Any suggestions?

Comment: a basic `foreach()` should do - [demo](https://3v4l.org/VP99S)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest using the function `array_filter` to perform your searching

The main element of this is the call back function with the `type or id` logic

```
function search_my_array( $array, $type, $id )
{
  return array_filter( $array, function( $item ) use ( $type, $id ){
    return $item['type'] === $type or ( is_array( $item['ids'] ) and in_array( $id, $item['ids'] ) );
  });
}

$array = array(
  array('name'=>'item-1','type'=>'typeA','ids'=>array(123,456,789)),
  array('name'=>'item-2','type'=>'typeA','ids'=>array(555,444,666)),
  array('name'=>'item-3','type'=>'typeB','ids'=>null),
  array('name'=>'item-4','type'=>'typeB','ids'=>array(555)),
);

$result = search_my_array( $array, 'typeA', 555 );
```

The result is the exact same array structure, just only with the three items you want, and then you can perform your `array_column` call

```
array_column( $result, 'name' );
```

---

Also if you don't always have the `type` or `ids` field, strengthen the validation with `isset`

```
return ( isset( $item['type'] ) and $item['type'] === $type ) or ( isset( $item['ids'] ) and is_array( $item['ids'] ) and in_array( $id, $item['ids'] ) );
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked beautifully!  I am not sure why the question was closed, I don't believe the other referenced question has the exact solution I was looking for.  But your answer is the correct one for my problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: Agreed, the other question returns a single key and not multiple matches